# jQuery Perfect Scroll - Start scroll bar in the Middle of the Container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I make my scrollbar start in the middle of my container using https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

I'm trying to cheat it by using

```
$(".trek_main_timeline_wrap").perfectScrollbar();

$(".trek_main_timeline_wrap .ps-scrollbar-y-rail").css({
                                                        "left" : "5px",
                                                        "top" : "200px"
                                                       });
```

But this is only pushing the scrollbar down, not the content inside of the container.

Comment: can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Could you give us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 11):

You would just use `scrollTop` and `update`:

```
$('.ps-container').scrollTop(100).perfectScrollbar('update');
```